How to connect one observation to two corresponding observations in a box-and-whisker plot with ggplot?
I am trying to visualize a series of linked observations (I do not say paired because there are three per experimental unit) using a box-and-whisker plot. Unfortunately, each observation in one category (g) is paired with two observations in the other category (ng). I would like to make a box-and-whisker plot where this is shown explicitly - each point in category g is connected by a line to each of two points in category ng. I cannot figure out how to ensure that each g is connected to both ng, rather than just one. Code below.
Below is a dummy tibble in the format of my data:
dataobject <- tibble::tibble(
  # grouping variable - each unique value is a single ~1000 m^2 study area w/ three quadrats
  rg = factor(c("ang2", "ang2", "ang2", "ang3", "ang3", "ang3", "ang4", "ang4", "ang4")),
  # levels of factor under study. Of three quadrats per group, two are ng and one is g
  GvNG = c("g", "ng", "ng", "g", "ng", "ng", "g", "ng", "ng"),
  # Calculated Pielou's evenness, the response variable
  PielouE = c(0.620, 0.913, 0.619, 0.537, 0.608, 0.952, 0.709, 0.688, 0.736))

Using this ggplot code I can get halfway there, but each g point is paired with only one ng point.
ggplot(dataobject, aes(x = GvNG, y = PielouE)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = GvNG), alpha = 0.4, width = 0.4, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(group = rg), position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), size = 2) +
  geom_line(data = dataobject %>% arrange(rg), aes(group = rg), color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ng" = "blue", "g" = "yellow")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Condition",y = "Pielou's Evenness", fill = "Condition")


How can I connect each g both corresponding ng?

You could use geom_path on a reordered data frame. Be careful with jittering points and lines. You need to add a seed to ensure they align.
mutate(dataobject, id=cumsum(GvNG=="ng") + (GvNG=="g")*1.5, .by=rg) |>
  arrange(id) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = GvNG, y = PielouE)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = GvNG), alpha = 0.4, width = 0.4, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, seed=1), size = 2) +
  geom_path(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, seed=1), aes(group=rg)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ng" = "blue", "g" = "yellow")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Condition",y = "Pielou's Evenness", fill = "Condition")




The jitter makes it hard to line up the points with the segments, but if you don't require that, this is one solution
Rearrange the data
library(tidyr)

data_rearranged <- dataobject |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = GvNG, values_from = PielouE, values_fn = list) |>
  unnest(everything())

data_rearranged
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   rg        g    ng
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ang2  0.62  0.913
#> 2 ang2  0.62  0.619
#> 3 ang3  0.537 0.608
#> 4 ang3  0.537 0.952
#> 5 ang4  0.709 0.688
#> 6 ang4  0.709 0.736

Then, replace geom_line with geom segment.

ggplot(dataobject, aes(x = GvNG, y = PielouE)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = GvNG), alpha = 0.4, width = 0.4, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(group = rg), position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), size = 2) +
  geom_segment(data = df2, aes(x = "g", y = g, xend = "ng", yend = ng)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("ng" = "blue", "g" = "yellow")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Condition",y = "Pielou's Evenness", fill = "Condition")


